# What do these options do to an already checked out file in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, team-foundation-server

In the following image
[image: Get Specific Version]

I am trying to get a specific version from TFS.
it has two options. One is to overwrite writeable files that are not checked out (which obviously does not affect checked out files that are set as pending changes) and the other says that it overwrites all files.
In the second one, will it overwrite checked out files that have been edited locally or will it preserve those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS will detect a conflict between the requested version on the server, and the files you have checked out locally.

In the "Pending changes" window, you'll be able to select whether to keep the local, checked out files or whether to replace them with the server version.

[image: Pending changes window]

Comment: so more or less like get latest

Comment: Yes exactly right